# Undefined function in DrScheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

Hey i'm just trying to write some code in DrScheme:
((function (x) (* x x)) 2)

but i got a message saying:
reference to undefined identifier: function

I'm using language "Essentials of Programming languages (3rd ed.)" and the version of DrScheme is 4.2.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

umm... that is not Scheme. You probably want:

```
((lambda (x) (* x x)) 2)
```

Comment: ah, i copied the example code from An introduction to scheme (http://www.acm.org/crossroads/xrds1-2/scheme.html)
should i switch to another intro..?

Comment: I see that at the bottom the document they say that "We finally note that the syntax we have adopted above is slightly different than that of standard Scheme...."

Answer (score 0):

should probably be

```
((lambda(x)(* x x))2)
```

or

```
((fun(x)(* x x))2)
```